# Chromium Edge extension publishing API

Tags: microsoft-edge, microsoft-edge-extension

Recently I starter to work on my Chromium MS Edge extension and I want to use CI/CD pipeline with step for publishing extension to [MS add-on store](https://microsoftedge.microsoft.com/addons/Microsoft-Edge-Extensions-Home?hl=en-US).
Google chrome extension can be published using [webstore API](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/using_webstore_api). Is it possible to use something similar with new Edge?

Comment: There is no extension publishing API available to publish the extension to the MS add-on store. Does the suggestion I provided you in the answer to help you to get the answer for your question? If yes, you can try to accept the answer. It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try to check the documentation for publishing the Edge (Chromium) extension to the MS add-on store.

It looks like at present there is no extension publishing API available to publish the extension to the MS add-on store.

To get detailed information about publishing the Edge (Chromium) extension to the MS add-on store you can refer to the link below.

[Publish An Extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions-chromium/publish/publish-extension)

Comment: I too would like an api. Firefox and Chrome both have apis. :( Make it really annoying to upload with CI/CD